# Identify slots in Angular 8 Multiprojection with ng-content

Tags: angular, angular8, ng-content

i am trying to build a simple dashboard component using Angular 8; each item contained in the dashboard can be anything.
I built two different component, one for the dashboard itself (the main container) and the second one for identify the area in the dashboard (this will receive the widget component list).

At the moment my solution is very simple. Basically, i use the **ng-content** to project my transcluded element in the main component.
I show you some code

A generic dashboard container:

```
<my-dashboard>
  <my-area widgets="[]"></my-area>
  <my-area widgets="[]"></my-area>
  <my-area widgets="[]"></my-area>
</my-dashboard>
```

The **my-dashboard** component is simply this:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Using this approach, verything work, but i do not have any access to single istance of the projected component as we have for example when we know exactly the slots. If i want for example to get information of a certain component from my dahboard component, this is not possible.
Is this the correct approach? I could not find much information about the content projection on the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

this is what ContentChildren or ContentChild decorators are for, in your dashboard component: (assuming  component exported as MyAreaComponent)

```
@ContentChildren(MyAreaComponent)
myAreaComponents: QueryList<MyAreaComponent>;

ngAfterContentInit() { // this is where ContentChildren are available
  console.log(this.myAreaComponents);
}
```